# How to create a static website generator in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, cra

Tech stack - Node.js, [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) for the database, [Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project) CMS for editing and API, React - my application.

I have a database with a long list of entries and a ready-to-use application that allows users to read data from the database. I need to be able to generate a simple website with a single entity from my database as a source to fill the template.

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGzwm.jpg)

Here is a mock-up. Hopefully, it will make things a bit clearer.

**Clarification**

After a day of thinking about the task, I believe I need something like a simplest static website generator - an application that will allow me to select a single bit of data from the list and generate a small website filled with it. The end goal is to get a website in some subfolder of my application where I can get it and use it however I need.

A bit more about specifics:

- It will be used locally
- Security can be neglected
- Running always in development is not a problem (just in case, thinking about additional question #2)

Few additional questions:

1. Is it possible to run NPM scripts from the application (like `npm build`)
2. Is there any way to show one component in development mode, but replace it with another during building for production?

```
    App.js
    //...

    function App() {
    if() {
      return <AdminUI /> // This one is to be shown in development mode
    } else {
      return <Website /> // This one is to be used instead of AdminUI in the build
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Well, I'm digging a path to create a site generator and so far I come up with the following basic plan:

- Get my template ready
- Create a new directory for my website
- Copy a template to the new folder
- Get an HTML file, parse it to a string to modify
- Swap some bits with my data
- Save to a file from the modified string
- repeat if needed for other files.

If that works as expected, the whole process probably might be improved by moving from a fixed template to a component, that will be prepared with a JavaScript bundler and started with the help of something like node-cmd (to run shell commands from my application)...

Comment: What you want to achieve seems quite complex, you need a full architecture probably. The simplest is to have your own npm registry (e.g. JFrog) and push your mini-component there, and keep that. As an alternative, you might consider IFrames as well.

On the less desirable side, you could also setup a (convolute) CI/CD pipeline to achieve what you want (e.g. Jervis / Jenkins). Even more convolute, a script to build for you (e.g. Grunt).

What could help is some diagram of components and some mockup image of what you want to achieve, because it's a bit difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Agree, I did not explain my goal clear enough, so after a day of thinking I rewrote my question and added a mockup.

Answer (score 0):

What you want could be achievable, but if it's just a string and little else, I'd say it's much simpler to fetch the data at startup from a given file, and populate from there. You can put a JSON file under the *public* folder (together with other static data, like images) and have the file being your configuration.

In the *App.js* file, write an *async componentDidMount()* and you can do an *await axios.get("")* with your configuration.

So *App.js* would look like (code written on the fly, didn't check in an IDE):

```
  export class App extends React.App {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { loading: true, };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
      const response = await axios.get("your/data.json");
      this.setState({ loading: false, ... whatever})
    }

    render = () => (
      <>
         (this.state.loading && <div>Still loading...</div>)
         (this.state.adminData && <AdminUI data={this.state.admingData} />)
         (this.state.devData && <Website data={this.state.devData} />)
      </>
    )
  }
```

If you don't care about security, wouldn't be much simpler like this? And if you use [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) you'll have a much much simpler life in handling the data too.

Maybe it's worth doing an AdminUI to generate the JSON, and the another UI which reads the JSON, so you end up doing two UIs. The template-generated UI could even ask for a JSON file to bootstrap directly to the user, if it simplifies... In general, an approach based on simple JSON sounds a lost simpler than going for a [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) pipeline.

Comment: What's the downside / catch to doing it this way?

Need to do something similar, except on a unique subdomain in next.js. Seems really easy, just store the users 'website' as a json, and pull it from the database whenever the user visits the corresponding subdomain.

Comment: The other approach is over-engineering, the downside here is that you have a two-steps process: first load the webpage, second load the json and render it. A static website would be faster (you only have one step, load the rendered page). That being said, every use case is different, so cannot ensure it applies to you! ^^